# How do you set the default window size in MacVim?

Tags: macvim

The default window size appears to be 24x80 but I'd prefer to set it so new windows appear in the size 50x90. Is there a way to set this default?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try setting the following line in ~/.gvimrc

`set lines=50 columns=90`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the full `set lines=## columns=##` but it did not work.

What I found is that using two `set` commands, one for each option, did work:

```
set lines=##
set columns=##
```

Comment: In what way did it "not work" ? For me, this worked just fine in one line - used in the .gvimrc. Your's might work, too, but I dont see why the other thing should not. Maybe it ahoiuld be rather a comment than an own solution...

Answer (score 0):

Like Gren said, but for the command line. On my Mac the --geometry argument is not supported

```
alias gv='mvim -c "set lines=50 columns=98" -p'
```